# Spark UDF: defining a function for UDF using "val" works correctly but defining using "def" does not

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a few functions to be used as UDFs in spark.  I wrote the same function twice: once using `val myFunc` and once using `def myFunc`.  When I register the function with spark, I notice that the version using `def myFunc` will return an error while the function written using `val` will compile fine.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Example {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    val myFunc = (x: Double, y: Double) => {
      x.toString + y.toString
    }
    val myUDF = spark.sqlContext.udf.register("myFunc", (x: Double, y: Double) => myFunc(x, y))
}
```

This example above will compile fine.  However, if I change the way I create my function to use `def` it will no longer compile.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Example {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    def myFunc(x: Double, y: Double): String = {
      x.toString + y.toString
    }
    val myUDF = spark.sqlContext.udf.register("myFunc", (x: Double, y: Double) => myFunc(x, y))
}
```

The above when compiled will throw this error:

```
No TypeTag available for String
val myUDF = spark.sqlContext.udf.register("myFunc", (x: Double, y: Double) => myFunc(x, y))
                                         ^
```

Does anyone know why one version works and the other does not compile?

EDIT: Here is my gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'

    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.10', version: '2.1.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.10',    version: '2.1.1'
}
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Could provide a [mcve], including build definition?

Comment: Compiles just fine with scala 2.11.8 and spark 2.2.1

Comment: Still don't know why it's work for others but not me.  Another solution I found is to add `compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.8'` to build file and now it works correctly